# Microeconomics - preference relations proof - Why is this logic invalid?

Tags: microeconomics

I'm going through various preference relation proofs using the various axioms (eg convexity), trying to get more comfortable with the mathematical tools before my class starts in about six weeks' time.

Can someone please explain to me why the highlighted step is invalid? Ie, basic algebra rearranging seems to lead to an obviously incorrect conclusion. Is the algebraic operation assuming that the preference relation maps linearly, or something like that? Many thanks.

[image: Concave preferences]

Answer (score 8):

Terms such as $a$ or $ta+(1-t)b$ are consumption bundles, not numbers, and $\succ$ is not the same as $>$, so you cannot simply "subtract" $ta$ from both sides of an expression or "divide" both sides by $1-t$ as though this were an inequality in the real numbers. To work in the real numbers you have to use utilities, e.g. write $u(ta+(1-t)b)<u(a)$. Then it should become clear why you can't go on as you did.

Comment: This seems to depend more on $\prec$ being different from $<$? Consumption bundles usually have an algebraic representation (a vector) that would admit such manipulations, i.e. if $$ta +(1-t)b << a$$ then $$b << a.$$ So $a$ and $b$ being bundles is not really the problem.

Comment: @Giskard, I think this is in some sense implied by $a$ and $b$ not being numbers. The relation $<$ is only defined on numbers, after all. (The relation $<<$ is defined on vectors, but this can't be the interpretation the questioner had in mind, since then even the first line of his "proof" would be clearly wrong.)

Comment: I could also define $\prec$ on *numbers* in such a way that the above calculation is invalid, so I still think the crucial point is that $\prec$ does not allow these manipulations the way $<$ does.

Comment: @Giskard, can we say it is both? If I prefer 3 apples to 5 bananas, then it is wrong to write "$3 > 5$". But neither "$3\succ 5$" nor "3 apples $>$ 5 bananas" is well-defined, so this translation is wrong because (i) bundles are not numbers AND (ii) $\succ$ is not $>$.

Comment: Thanks very much everyone.

Answer (score 4):

The answer in short is that adding the same vector to both the sides need not preserve the preference relation because the added utilities to both sides may be different even when the same vector is added. The additional utility also depends on the quantities of all the goods already owned. For example, suppose having 10 bananas is indifferent to having 10 oranges. We add the same vector of 5 bananas and 0 oranges in both the cases. But it is obvious that the 5 bananas would add much more utility in the first case (as the preferences are concave in your example) than in the second case.

More mathematically, let's say the number of commodities is $n$, then $a, b$ are both $n$ dimensional vectors, $t$ is a positive real number less than 1.

The initial LHS is: $ta + (1-t)b$ ($:=c$) which, say, gives you the utility, $u(ta + (1-t)b)$

The initial RHS is: $a$ which gives you the utility $u(a)$

$ta + (1-t)b \prec a$ simply means $u(ta + (1-t)b) < u(a)$

Then you added $-ta$ to both the sides.

The new LHS is: $(1-t)b$, which gives you the utility $u((1-t)b)$

The increase in utility in the LHS is: $u((1-t)b) - u(ta + (1-t)b)$

The new RHS is: $(1-t)a$ which gives you the utility $u((1-t)a)$

The increase in utility in the RHS is: $u((1-t)a) - u(a)$

Adding $-ta$ to both sides would mean adding equal utility to both sides iff $u((1-t)b) - u(ta + (1-t)b) = u((1-t)a) - u(a)$.

This is a condition only some and not all utility functions would satisfy. Adding unequal amounts of utility may lead tobreversal of the preference relation.

For example, let $u(x,y) = y/(2- x^2), a=(1,1), b=(0,2), t=0.5$.

The initial relations hold, that is, $a$ ~ $b$ and $c \prec a$. But adding $-ta$ to both sides leads to adding unequal amounts of utility, LHS's utility increases by $-5/14$ while the RHS's utility increases by $-5/7$, and now the LHS is preferred.

Comment: The example is somewhat suboptimal, with infinite and negative utilities for $x\ge\sqrt{2}$.